# How to change color of the material ui element without re-rendering the site or using MuiThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I recently added to this project, in this project they use material ui for some elements and some HTML elements for the rest of the elements. they write the style for both of them

- Now they ask me to change the minimum code for changing the theme, this is the style for **material ui** part

```js
        // this is UserOptions.js
        const chooseTheme = [theme]
        const themeStyle = 
                localStorage.getItem('theme') === null ? 
        chooseTheme[0]['IGS'] : chooseTheme[0][localStorage.getItem('theme')];
        const styles = theme => ({
           button: {
                backgroundColor: themeStyle.bkgTextColor,
                color: themeStyle.dialogContentColor,
          },
       })
```

this is the textfield I used for changing the theme

```js
    <TextField
        select
        style ={{direction: 'center', width: '100px'}}
        type= 'select'
    >
        <option value={'Light'}>Light</option>
        <option value={'Dark'}>Dark</option>
    </TextField>
```

and I used this code for **exporting** part

```
export default withStyles(styles)(UserOptions);
```

- this is the **Theme.js** file

```js
       export const Light = {
              bkgTextColor: '#19417C';
              dialogContentColor: '#E7EFFA';
       }
```

when user change the otion of the textfield, the html element color changes but i should refresh the page to see the material ui elements color changed, what should I do to make the material ui color change without using **MuiThemeProvider** (maybe i should redirect to this page after re-render the page and i don't know how)

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you host this on codesandbox

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti sorry I cant

Comment: I did not ask you to host whole code, I can understand there are company policies, I'm asking you to host small piece so that issue can be reproduced.